# Animate bezier straight lines

Tags: ios, animation, line, uibezierpath

I want how to animate a bezier straight line like see-saw. Can somebody please suggest. Reference link for animation how does it should look (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bjCx128BZK8).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say how you rendered this `UIBezierPath`, but if you for example added it as a `CAShapeLayer` you can just apply a `CAKeyframeAnimation` to it:

```
// create simple path

let path = UIBezierPath()
path.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 50, y: view.bounds.size.height / 2))
path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: view.bounds.size.width - 50, y: view.bounds.size.height / 2))

// create `CAShapeLayer` from that path

let layer = CAShapeLayer()
layer.path = path.CGPath
layer.lineWidth = 10
layer.strokeColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
layer.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor

view.layer.addSublayer(layer)

// animate it

let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "transform")
var values = [NSValue]()
for var x: CGFloat = 0.0; x < CGFloat(M_PI * 4); x += CGFloat(M_PI * 4 / 100.0) {
    var transform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(view.frame.size.width/2, view.frame.size.height/2, 0.0)
    transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, sin(x) / 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
    transform = CATransform3DTranslate(transform, -view.frame.size.width/2, -view.frame.size.height/2, 0.0)

    values.append(NSValue(CATransform3D: transform))
}
animation.duration = 2
animation.values = values

layer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "transform")
```

That yields:

[image]

Or you could add the `CAShapeLayer` to a view and then use the block-based `UIView` animation to rotate the view. The basic idea would be the same.

If you want to do something more sophisticated, you can use `CADisplayLink`, either updating the `path` for the `CAShapeLayer` (as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14571148/ios-animate-transformation-from-a-line-to-a-bezier-curve/14571854#14571854)) or updating the properties used by `UIView` subclass and then call `setNeedsDisplay`.